# How to enforce a constraint requiring dates to be date only (or 12:00AM) in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Consider the model

```
public class Patient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

I can use this model with code-first Entity Framework to store a patient record in the `Patients` table. It's generally understood that `DateOfBirth` never refers to the time of birth, it should conceptually be a date-only field - not a date time. However `DateTime` objects always have a time component, so it seems reasonably common to represent this as a DateTime with the time set to midnight.

Is there a way to enforce this constraint in the database with code-first EF? Ideally an attempt to save a `DateOfBirth` with a time component other than midnight should fail.

Comment: in your db schema, can you use sql-server [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) type instead of datetime2 ?

Comment: (what I think will probably happen is that any time information will probably be *ignored*, though, not failing)